# Part number suffix meaning (,135 ,115)

Tags: bom

When making a BOM I used a component which goes by part number BC847BW,135. It is available on [Mouser](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/BC847BW135?qs=me8TqzrmIYWjfiGiujwNkg%3D%3D) and [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/BC847BW135/1727-6192-1-ND/2762690).

An "alternative", is listed on [Farnell](https://uk.farnell.com/nexperia/bc847bw-115/transistor-npn-45v-0-1a-sot323/dp/1907650?iscrfnonsku=true&st=BC847BW,135): BC847BW,115

The [datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/BC847_SER-1598765.pdf) doesn't seem to mention what ",135" or ",115" means. I've seen this suffix on other Nexperia parts but it never made a difference to me until today, when it caused me some inconveniences with an assembly house.

So I'm curious as to what those numbers mean, and if the parts are different at all, or if its a packaging issue (reel size), etc.

p.s.: the issue I had with the assembly house is unrelated to the question, I had to suggest the ,115 part as an alternative to the ,135 part because on their database BC847BW,135 is listed as SOT23, so I just had to suggest a different part number with SOT323 footprint - the W suffix clearly indicates SOT323 on the datasheet but anyway)

update to the p.s.: they corrected their model on their database and will proceed with the ,135 part.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the only difference is how it is packaged on the reel for different PnP machines. The 135 is a standard reel size of 3000, the 115 is 10,000.

Comment: BC847BW,115 is also available on [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/BC847BW115?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2FWi7dklbCN21lXDfBc5XbLVUg%3D) and [Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/BC847BW115/1727-4853-1-ND/2531354)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those numbers are related to ordering and packaging, see https://www.nexperia.com/products/bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847BW.html and scroll to the ordering section.

The 115 is a 7" reel of 3k pieces, 135 is an 11 1/4" reel with 10k pieces.

Comment: I wonder how they come up with the numbers, I tried converting 7" to mm but it is about 178mm. Nice catch though, I wish they included that info on the datasheet. Thanks!